# What happens when a definite integral is differentiated?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let's say
$f: \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$
and
$$f(x)=\int_0^x f(t) ~\mathrm dt$$
I'm asked to find $f(\ln(5))$
so to do that I first differentiated $f(x)$, however as this is a definite integral, on differentiating, am I simply obtaining the differential on the interval $[0,x]$?

Comment: What happens when you Google Leibniz integral rule?

Comment: Well, if you differentiated $f(x)$ then what you differentiated was the indefinite integral, not the definite integral. But that isn't obviously helpful for evaluating $f(\ln 5)$. And of course if you differentiate the definite integral, which is a constant, you just get $0$, which is even less helpful.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to find $f(\ln{(5)})$, then what is the point of differentiating? Even if you differentiate, you would get $f'(x) = f(x)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which is more confusing.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133707/42969

Answer (score 3):

Just differentiate $f$ and get $f'(x)=f(x)$. Then write it

$e^{-x}f'(x)-e^{-x}f(x)=0$ giving $(e^{-x}f(x))'=0$ and hence $e^{-x}f(x)=c$

which gives $f(x)=e^{x}c$. But by the definition of $f$ we get $f(0)=0$ and thus $c=0$ which gives $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ and hence $f(\ln5)=0$.

An alternative way is to use Gronwall's lemma and get the result immediately!

Comment: The conslusion that $f'(x) = f(x)$ requires some extra justification, perhpaps by means of showing that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I agree! The OP does not give any information about$ f$, but I think that we have to assume that it is continuous. Because in order to define the integral $f$ must be in $L_{1}$ and then $f(x)$ is AC, and since $e^{-x}f(x)$ is AC and $(e^{-x}f(x))'=0$ a.e. then $e^{-x}f(x)$ is constant. See Royden. But it is easier to assume $f$ is continuous from the start.

Comment: A bit simpler: as you say, $f$ is $L^1$ so $\int \limits_0^x f(t) \, \text{d} t$ is AC, hence $f$ is AC and therefore continuous. By the way, the assumption OP has in mind is proably that $f$ is Riemann integrable, which is stronger than being $L^1$, but I wouldn't go as far as assuming it is continuous.

Comment: Exactly! But we also need that the derivative exists a.e. and use that if $g$ is AC and $g'(x)=0$ a.e. then $g(x)=c$.

Comment: Why? Once we get that $f$ is continuous, the Fundamental theorem of calculus asserts that $f' = f$ and the rest of your solution follows. In a sense, every regularity statement about $f$ implies a better regularity statement about the integral of $f$, which equals $f$, so we could even get that $f$ is smooth just by iterating this argument.

Comment: I agree! Another very easy way is to use Gronwall's inequality and get the result immediately. (Using as $y(x)=|f(x)|$ and $y(x)\leq\,\int_{0}^{x}y(t)dt$ and immediately get $y=0$ hence $f(x)=0$ (only assumption needed is $f$ continuous which we already have!